# why does tput lines return different values?

Tags: tclsh

I'm running a tclsh script and I'm trying to determine the number of lines in the terminal window. When I run the command from the command line I get the right number (70).

```
$ tclsh
% tput lines
70
```

But when I run the command from inside a puts/exec I get a different number (24).

```
$ tclsh
% puts [exec tput lines]
24
```

The number I'm looking for is 70... what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
[exec tput cols >@ stdout]
```

The reason is that without the >@ redirection, Tcl uses a pipe reading
from the child's stdout (to produce [exec]'s result). Hence tput's
ioctl()s operate on the pipe, which gets a default geometry unrelated
to the surrounding terminal.

**Reference:** https://groups.google.com/g/comp.lang.tcl/c/bX8wjU8Z2To

```
$ tput lines
43
$ tput cols
87
$ tclsh
% tput lines
43
% tput cols
87
% exec tput lines
24
% exec tput cols
80
% exec tput lines >@stdout
43
% exec tput cols >@stdout
87
%
```

Comment: I was looking for `lines` and `puts [exec tput lines >@ stdout]` worked as you suggest. The explanation is as I hoped but was uncertain.